# My post method dose not when I am trying to post in something

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I have a problem with post method, I can't post in something when I'm using postman. I always got Failed to Add!! in postman.

My post method

```
   public string Post(Temperatur Temp)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = @"
                insert into testTB(DevEUI_uplink) values
                ('" + Temp.DevEUI_uplink + @"')         
            ";


            string connectionString = "server=...;user id= admin;password = ....; database = smartlakes2";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
            using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.Fill(table);

            }

            return "Added Successfully!!";
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Failed to Add!!";

        }
    }
```

My model

```
 public class Temperatur
    {
        public string DevEUI_uplink { get; set; }

    }
```

And the table I create in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE testTB(  
    DevEUI_uplink json
);
```

I'm trying to add something like that in postman but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "DevEUI_uplink": "Hello"
}
```

Comment: where are u using post method?

Comment: try putting from body attribute on your post method argument, and use camel case in post man

Comment: Hi @Tamer, you should try to debug your application to get what exception you get and mention the exact issue (exception) in the question. There are few things to point out: 1. Is it correct to add `@` sign in your `query`? 2. As your query are doing Insertion, you should use [SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) but not `da.Fill(table)` as this is not a `SELECT` query.

Comment: 3. Please use Parameterized Query as concatenate value into query may lead to [Sql Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).